# TWriter добавляет спецсимволы в файл

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Нужно создать файл html и записать в него код. Использую для этого `TWriter`, но он добавляет спецсимволы. Например, в примере ниже я получаю такой результат в файле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  var
      fs: TFileStream;
      Writer: TWriter;
    begin
      fs := TFileStream.Create(FFileName, fmCreate);
      Writer := TWriter.Create(fs, 4096);
      Writer.WriteListBegin;
      try
        Writer.WriteString('test 1');
        Writer.WriteString('test 2');
        Writer.WriteString('test 3');
        Writer.WriteListEnd;
      finally
        Writer.Free;
        fs.Free;    
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: Расскажите, что делает `WriteListBegin` ?

Comment: WriteListBegin и WriteListEnd записывают в буфер значения. Что-то вроде разбивки по разделам. Пример брала с http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Seattle/en/TWriter_(Delphi)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TWriter` предназначен для структурированной записи информации в поток. Естественно, что при этом он записывает служебную информацию, отделяющую одни данные от других. В частности:

`WriteListBegin` записывает в выходной поток один байт со значением 1.

`WriteString` записывает данные в формате UTF8, но в зависимости от того, содержатся ли национальные символы или нет, а также в зависимости от длины строки - использует разные префиксы к данным. В Вашем случае используется запись байта со значением 6 (обозначает строку, содержащую только английские символы, длиной не более 255 байт) и байт длины строки (в вашем примере - значение 6).

Итого в начале файла оказываются значения:

```
1 - начало списка
6 - английская строка длиной не более 255 байт
6 - длина строки
t
e
s
t

1
```

Для записи "истинно текстового" файла стоит воспользоваться классом `TStringList` и его методом SaveToFile с указанием кодировки (желательно - `TEncoding.UTF8`):

```
myStringList:=TStringList.Create;
try
  myStringList.Add('test 1');
  myStringList.Add('тест 2');
  myStringList.SaveToFile('c:\temp\123.html',TEncoding.UTF8);
finally
  myStringList.Free;
end;
```

Также можно воспользоваться TStringStream, но это менее желательный способ, поскольку этот класс не записывает [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2). Отсюда могут возникнуть проблемы с кодировкой у читающих этот файл:

```
sStream := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
try
  sStream.WriteString('test1');
  sStream.WriteString('тест 2');
  sStream.SaveToFile('c:\temp\123.html');
finally
  sStream.Free;
end;
```